# Django Signals: The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing

Tags: django

I hope my title is enough to determine what the error is.

I have this code in my `models.py` (post_save)

```py
    class StudentsEnrolledSubject(models.Model):
        Students_Enrollment_Records = models.ForeignKey(StudentsEnrollmentRecord, related_name='+',
                                                        on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
        Subject_Section_Teacher = models.ForeignKey(SubjectSectionTeacher, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                                    null=True,blank=True)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=StudentsEnrollmentRecord)
    def create(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
        teachers = SubjectSectionTeacher.objects.filter(Sections=instance.Section,Education_Levels=instance.Education_Levels,Courses=instance.Courses)
        for each in teachers:
            if created and teachers.exists():
                StudentsEnrolledSubject.objects.update_or_create(
                        pk=each.id,
                        Students_Enrollment_Records=instance,
                        Subject_Section_Teacher=teachers.all()

                    )

    class StudentsEnrollmentRecord(models.Model):
        Student_Users = models.ForeignKey(StudentProfile, related_name='students', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    class SubjectSectionTeacher(models.Model):
        Education_Levels = models.ForeignKey(EducationLevel, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
        Courses = models.ForeignKey(Course, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
        Sections = models.ForeignKey(Section, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
        Subjects = models.ForeignKey(Subject, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
        Employee_Users = models.ForeignKey(EmployeeUser, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

when I used the `Subject_Section_Teacher=teachers.first()` i received no error but that is not what i want result, then i decide to change it to this `Subject_Section_Teacher=teachers.all()`

I just want the result to become this

[image]

not this

[image]

this is where I get/filter data

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're iterating over the `teachers` already, you should use `each` to pass the current `teacher` in the loop instead of `teachers.all()` which is invalid or `teachers.first()` which is always just the first teacher:

```
    for each in teachers:
        if created and teachers.exists():
            StudentsEnrolledSubject.objects.update_or_create(
                    pk=each.id,
                    Students_Enrollment_Records=instance,
                    Subject_Section_Teacher=each,
                )
```

Comment: nice one sir :)

Answer (score 0):

Update the code like this:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=StudentsEnrollmentRecord)
def create(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    teachers = SubjectSectionTeacher.objects.filter(Sections=instance.Section,Education_Levels=instance.Education_Levels,Courses=instance.Courses)
    for each in teachers:
        StudentsEnrolledSubject.objects.update_or_create(
                    pk=each.id,
                    Students_Enrollment_Records=instance,
                    Subject_Section_Teacher=each

                )
```

Comment: nice one again sir :)